# Selecting an option using fancy select

Tags: javascript, jquery, gumby-framework

I've got a fancy select with code similar to the following, yet adding the `selected=selected` attribute to one of the options (with JS) does not change which item is currently selected.

```
<li class="field">
  <div class="picker">
    <select>
      <option value="#" disabled>Favorite Doctor…</option>
      <option>Colin Baker</option>
      <option>Sylvester McCoy</option>
      <option>Paul McGann</option>
      <option>Christopher Eccleston</option>
      <option>David Tennant</option>
      <option>Matt Smith</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</li>
```

How can I change the selected option and have this change reflected in the select box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to trigger the change event after you set the selected option, for example:

```
$('option:eq(2)').prop('selected',true).trigger('change'); // or .change()
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cxy9Z/1/)**

Comment: Works and is much cleaner than my method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by setting the `select.val()` to the text of the option I'm trying to select.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by mending FS's code. It was using `:selected` as a selector. Changed it to `[selected="selected"]` and it behaved. Best to just avoid FS completely though, in my opinion. I inherited it on a project I'm working on.

Around line 56 in my copy, now changed to:

```
triggerHtml = settings.triggerTemplate(sel.find('[selected="selected"]'));
```